# Trouble getting started with AWS Lambda locally

Tags: aws-lambda, rider

I'm trying to get a simple dotnet lambda up and running using the Rider AWS toolkit - starting with the SAM HelloWorld sample project, but in creating, I run into this error

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not execute `sam init`!: [Cloning from https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates, Error: Unstable state when updating repo. Check that you have permissions to create/delete files in C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\AWS SAM directory or file an issue at https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues]
```

I checked the permissions on that directory, and I should have full read/write. I'm not seeing anyone else running into this particular problem online. Is this indicative of any other steps I missed along the way?

Comment: Have you found the solution ? I am having trouble with that issue ? Can you share your experience ?

Comment: I never figured it out and ended up using other tools. Looks like Bill may have a resolution in the answers though!

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is apparently a long filename issue.  There is a workaround here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3781#issuecomment-1081263942

What I did was:

1. Using regedit set `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled"` to `1`
2. With admin permissions, run `git config --system core.longpaths true`

Comment: As OP mentioned in github, the first step can be `New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force`